# joining table with itself using mysql

Tags: mysql

When I write this line on mysql on `phpmyadmin` using `mariadb` server getting unexpected error near `a.cpid = b.cid`

```
select a.cid, a.cname as 'cname', b.cname as 'pname'
from categories as a left OUTER JOIN as b ON a.cpid = b.cid
```

> MySQL said:
>   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as b ON a.cpid = b.cid LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack a table name (the second categories in below):

```
select a.cid, a.cname as 'cname', b.cname as 'pname' 
from categories as a 
left OUTER JOIN categories as b ON a.cpid = b.cid
```

Comment: Thanks man really how could i forgot this it wastes my hours to get me to right way perfect spot.

Comment: Why didnt approve these answer?? Weird xD

Comment: i was waiting for 11 minutes to be over while approving it was alerting me you cannot before 11 minutes lol. sorry for your answer is technically approved xd